# Controlling my output

Tags: python, string, list, tuples, pyparsing

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import sys
import os
import parser
sys.path.append('Z:\_protomotion\Prog\HelperScripts')
import GetDir
sys.path.append('Z:/Blender_Roto')
filename = 'diving_board.shape4ae'
infile = 'Z:/Blender_Roto/'
#import bpy
#from mathutils import Vector

#below are taken from mocha export
x_width =2048
y_height = 778
z_depth = 0
frame = 20

import re

data_directory = 'Z:/Blender_Roto/' # windows
data_file = 'diving_board.shape4ae'
fullpath = data_directory + data_file


print("====init=====")

file = open(fullpath)
for line in file:
current_line = line

# massive room for optimized code here.

# this assumes the last element of the line containing the words
# "Units Per Second" is the number we are looking for.
# this is a non float number, generally.
if current_line.find("Units Per Second") != -1:
    fps = line_split = float(current_line.split()[-1])
    print("Frames Per Second:", fps)

# source dimensions
if current_line.find("Source Width") != -1:
    source_width = line_split = int(current_line.split()[-1])
    print("Source Width:", source_width)

if current_line.find("Source Height") != -1:
    source_height = line_split = int(current_line.split()[-1])
    print("Source Height:", source_height)

# aspect ratios
if current_line.find("Source Pixel Aspect Ratio") != -1:
    source_px_aspect = line_split = int(current_line.split()[-1])
    print("Source Pixel Aspect Ratio:", source_px_aspect)

if current_line.find("Comp Pixel Aspect Ratio") != -1:
    comp_aspect = line_split = int(current_line.split()[-1])
    print("Comp Pixel Aspect Ratio:", comp_aspect)


# assumption, ae file can contain multiple mocha shapes.
# without knowing the exact format i will limit the script
# to deal with one mocha shape being animated N frames.

# this gathers the shape details, and frame number but does not
# include error checking yet.
if current_line.find("XSpline") != -1:

    # record the frame number.
    print(len(points))
    frame = re.search("\s*(\d*)\s*XSpline", current_line)
    if frame.group(1) != None:
        frame = frame.group(1)
        print("frame:", frame)

    # pick part the part of the line that deals with geometry
    match = re.search("XSpline\((.+)\)\n", current_line)

    line_to_strip = match.group(1)
    points = re.findall('(\(.*?\))', line_to_strip)

(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5) = points
print (p1)
#print (p2)
#print (p3)
#print (p4)
#print (p5)

file.close()
```

Here is my output:

```
====init=====
Frames Per Second: 24.0
Source Width: 2048
Source Height: 778
Source Pixel Aspect Ratio: 1
Comp Pixel Aspect Ratio: 1
5
frame: 20
(0.793803,0.136326,0,0.5,0)
```

from this output I want to be able to assign (0.793803) to the variable 'point1x' (0.136326) to the variable point1y (0) to the variable point1z (0.5) to the variable point1w and (0) to the variable point1s.

So instead of just outputting `(0.793803,0.136326,0,0.5,0)` I want it to give me the values individually

so:

```
point1x: 0.793803
point1y: 0.136326
point1z: 0
point1w: 0.5
point1s: 0
```

Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Your first question is EXACTLY the same and still open. Edit / Update it, don't post a new one with the same question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have `points`, if you **know** it will always be a comma-seperated list of decimal numbers, simply do something like this:

```
points = points.split(",")
# points = ["0.793803","0.136326","0","0.5","0"]
# Now you can use John Gaines suggestion
# to unpack your variables
point1x, point1y, point1z, point1w = points
```

If you don't know how many points there will be to unpack for any given entry, but you know the max, simply check `points` length after you split and add the appropriate number of `None` entries to the list:

```
# Somewhere earlier
max_entries = 5
# ... snip ...
# points = ["0.793803","0.136326","0"]
cur_len = len(points)
if cur_len > max_entries:
    raise ValueError("%d points discovered in %s.  Max entries is %d" % (cur_len, points, max_entries)
 if cur_len != max_entries:
     points += [None] * (max_entries - cur_len)
 # Continue from here
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sean, that was the most useful response I've gotten in a long time. If I had enough rep I would vote up your answer haha

Comment: Not necessary to convert a list to a tuple to unpack directly into program variables.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a tuple, in which case, the python statement for what you want is:

```
point1x, point1y, point1z, point1w = (0.793803,0.136326,0,0.5,0)
```

Comment: Gaines Jr Ya that is correct, and thank you for the response, but I failed to mention that it needs to be able to take it from a file output, and the file will have multiple values that change so I can't assign the points directly to the numbers... sorry that was completely my fault